# Progressbar перестал работать

Tags: python-2.x, progress-bar

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python -u
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    #******************************************************************************
    #
    # get_reformagkh_data-v2.py
    # ---------------------------------------------------------
    # Grab reformagkh.ru data on buildings, put it in the CSV table.
    # More: https://github.com/nextgis/reformagkh
    #
    # Usage: 
    #      usage: get_reformagkh_data-v2.py [-h] [-o ORIGINALS_FOLDER] id output_name
    #      where:
    #           -h           show this help message and exit
    #           id           Region ID
    #           -o,overwrite Overwite all, will write over previously downloaded files
    #           output_name  Where to store the results (path to CSV file)
    #           -of ORIGINALS_FOLDER  Folder to save original html files. Skip saving if empty.
    # Examples:
    #      python get_reformagkh_data-v2.py 2280999 data/housedata2.csv -o html_orig
    #
    # Copyright (C) 2014-2016 Maxim Dubinin (sim@gis-lab.info)
    # Created: 18.03.2014
    #
    # This source is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
    # the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free
    # Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your option)
    # any later version.
    #
    # This code is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY
    # WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
    # FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License for more
    # details.
    #
    # A copy of the GNU General Public License is available on the World Wide Web
    # at <http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html>. You can also obtain it by writing
    # to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston,
    # MA 02111-1307, USA.
    #
    #******************************************************************************

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib2
    import csv
    from progressbar import *
    import socket
    import argparse
    from collections import namedtuple
    from time import sleep
    import requesocks
    from stem import Signal
    from stem.control import Controller

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('id', help='Region ID')
    parser.add_argument('output_name', help='Where to store the results (path to CSV file)')
    parser.add_argument('-o','--overwrite', action="store_true", help='Overwite all, will write over previously downloaded files.')
    parser.add_argument('-of','--originals_folder', help='Folder to save original html files. Skip saving if empty.')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.originals_folder:
        if not args.originals_folder.endswith('\\'): args.originals_folder = args.originals_folder + '\\'
        if not os.path.exists(args.originals_folder): os.mkdir(args.originals_folder)

    def console_out(text):
        #write httplib error messages to console
        time_current = datetime.datetime.now()
        timestamp = time_current.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        f_errors.write(timestamp + ': '+ text)

    def get_content(link):
        numtries = 5
        timeoutvalue = 40

        for i in range(1,numtries+1):
            try:
                res = session.get(link).text
            except:
                time.sleep(3)
                res = ''
            else:
                break

        if res == '':
            print('Session time out')
            sys.exit() 

        return res

    def urlopen_house(link,id):
        #fetch html data on a house

        res = get_content(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(res), 'html.parser')
        captcha = check_captcha(soup)

        while captcha == True:
            res = get_content(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(res), 'html.parser')
            captcha = check_captcha(soup)
            change_proxy()

        if args.originals_folder:
            f = open(args.originals_folder + id + ".html","wb")
            f.write(res.encode('utf-8'))
            f.close()

        return res

    def change_proxy():
        with Controller.from_port(port = 9151) as controller:
                controller.authenticate(password="password")
                controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

    def extract_value(tr):
        #extract value for general attributes
        res = tr.findAll('td')[1].text.strip()

        return res

    def extract_subvalue(tr,num):
        #extract value for general attributes
        res = tr.findAll('tr')[num].text.strip()

        return res

    def check_size(link):

        res = get_content(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(res), 'html.parser')
        captcha = check_captcha(soup)

        while captcha == True:
            res = get_content(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(res), 'html.parser')
            captcha = check_captcha(soup)
            change_proxy()

        divs = soup.findAll('div', { 'class' : 'clearfix' })
        table = divs[1].find('table', { 'class' : 'col_list' })
        size = table.findAll('td')[3].text.replace(u' ед.','').replace(' ','')

        return size

    def get_house_list(link):
        size = check_size(link)
        if size == 0: size = check_size(link)

        pages = (int(size) / 10000) + 1

        houses_ids = []
        for page in range(1,pages+1):
            res = get_content(link + '&page=' + str(page) + '&limit=10000')
            soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(res), 'html.parser')
            captcha = check_captcha(soup)

            while captcha == True:
                res = get_content(link + '&page=' + str(page) + '&limit=10000')
                soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(res), 'html.parser')
                captcha = check_captcha(soup)
                change_proxy()

            tds = soup.findAll('td')
            for td in tds:
                if td.find('a') is not None:
                    if td.find('a').has_attr('href') and 'myhouse' in td.find('a')['href']:
                        house_id = td.find('a')['href'].split('/')[4]
                        houses_ids.append(house_id)

        return houses_ids

    def get_data_links(id):
        f_atd = open('atd.csv','rb')
        csvreader = csv.reader(f_atd, delimiter=',')
        regs = []
        for row in csvreader:
            if id in row:
                r = region(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5])
                regs.append(r)

        return regs

    def check_captcha(soup):
        captcha = soup.find('form', { 'name' : 'request_limiter_captcha'})    
        if captcha != None or u'Каптча' in soup.text or 'captcha' in str(soup): 
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get_housedata(link,house_id,lvl1_name,lvl1_id,lvl2_name,lvl2_id):
        #process house data to get main attributes

        if args.originals_folder:
            if not os.path.isfile(args.originals_folder + '/' + house_id + ".html"):
                try:
                    res = urlopen_house(link + 'view/' + house_id,house_id)
                except:
                    f_errors.write(link + 'view/' + house_id + '\n')
                    res = False
            else:
                res = open(args.originals_folder + '/' + house_id + ".html",'rb').read()
        else:
           try:
               res = urlopen_house(link + 'view/' + house_id,house_id)
           except:
               f_errors.write(link + 'view/' + house_id + '\n')
               res = False

        if res != False:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(res),'html.parser')
            f_ids.write(link + 'view/' + house_id + ',' + house_id + '\n')

            if len(soup) > 0 and 'Time-out' not in soup.text and '502 Bad Gateway' not in soup.text: #u'Ошибка' not in soup.text

                addr = soup.find('span', { 'class' : 'float-left loc_name_ohl width650 word-wrap-break-word' })
                address = addr.contents[0].strip()
                if len(addr.contents) > 2:
                    fias = 0
                else:
                    fias = 1

                #GENERAL
                div = soup.find('div', { 'class' : 'fr' })
                tables = div.findAll('table')
                table0 = tables[0]
                trs = table0.findAll('tr')

                mgmt_company = trs[0].findAll('td')[1].text.strip()                  #gen8 Домом управляет
                if trs[0].findAll('td')[1].find('a'):
                    mgmt_company_link = 'http://www.reformagkh.ru' + trs[0].findAll('td')[1].find('a')['href']
                    mgmt_company_link = mgmt_company_link.split('?')[0]
                else:
                    mgmt_company_link = ''

                table1 = tables[1]
                trs = table1.findAll('tr')
                status = '' #trs[1].findAll('td')[1].text.strip()                    #gen7 Состояние дома (куда-то исчезло в последней версии)

                table1 = tables[1]
                trs = table1.findAll('tr')
                #area = float(trs[2].findAll('td')[1].text.strip().replace(' ',''))  #gen1 Общая площадь
                #year = trs[6].findAll('td')[1].text.strip()                          #gen6 Год ввода в экспл
                lastupdate = trs[8].findAll('td')[1].text.strip()                    #gen2 Последнее изменение анкеты
                lastupdate = ' '.join(lastupdate.replace('\n','').split())
                servicedate_start = trs[10].findAll('td')[1].text.strip()            #gen3 Дата начала обслуживания дома
                servicedate_end = '' #trs[5].findAll('td')[1].text.strip()           #gen4 Плановая дата прекращения обслуживания дома

                #TODO extract lat/long coords from script
                if 'center' in soup.findAll('script')[11]:
                    lat,lon = soup.findAll('script')[11].text.split('\n')[3].split('[')[1].split(']')[0].split(',')
                else:
                    lat,lon = soup.findAll('script')[12].text.split('\n')[3].split('[')[1].split(']')[0].split(',')

                #PASSPORT
                ##GENERAL
                divs = soup.findAll('div', { 'class' : 'numbered' })
                div0 = divs[0]
                trs = div0.findAll('tr')
                lentrs = len(trs)
                if lentrs > 58: 
                    trs_offset = lentrs - 58
                else:
                    trs_offset = 0

                year = extract_value(trs[3])                            #5 Год ввода в эксплуатацию
                serie = extract_value(trs[5])                            #1 Серия
                house_type = extract_value(trs[7])                       #4 Тип жилого дома
                capfond = extract_value(trs[9])                          #5 Способ формирования фонда капитального ремонта
                avar = extract_value(trs[11])                            #6 Дом признан аварийным
                levels_max = extract_subvalue(trs[12], 1)                #7 Этажность: макс
                levels_min = extract_subvalue(trs[12], 3)                #7 Этажность: мин
                doors = extract_value(trs[18])                           #9 Количество подъездов
                room_count = extract_value(trs[23])                      #10 Количество помещений
                room_count_live = extract_value(trs[26])                 #10 Количество помещений: жилых
                room_count_nonlive = extract_value(trs[28])              #10 Количество помещений: нежилых
                area = extract_value(trs[31]).replace(' ','')            #11 Общая площадь дома
                area_live = extract_value(trs[34]).replace(' ','')       #11 Общая площадь дома, жилых
                area_nonlive = extract_value(trs[36]).replace(' ','')    #11 Общая площадь дома, нежилых

                area_gen = extract_value(trs[38]).replace(' ','')        #11 Общая площадь помещений, входящих в состав общего имущества
                area_land = extract_value(trs[41]).replace(' ','')       #12 Общие сведения о земельном участке, на котором расположен многоквартирный дом
                area_park = extract_value(trs[43]).replace(' ','')       #12 Общие сведения о земельном участке, на котором расположен многоквартирный дом
                cadno = trs[44].findAll('td')[1].text                    #12 кад номер

                energy_class = extract_value(trs[48 + trs_offset])       #13 Класс энергоэффективности
                blag_playground = extract_value(trs[51 + trs_offset])    #14 Элементы благоустройства
                blag_sport = extract_value(trs[53 + trs_offset])         #14 Элементы благоустройства
                blag_other = extract_value(trs[55 + trs_offset])         #14 Элементы благоустройства
                other = extract_value(trs[57 + trs_offset])              #14 Элементы благоустройства

                ##meter devices
                result = {}
                table = soup.findAll('table', {'class': 'overhaul-services-table'})[-1]
                for section in table.findAll('tbody'):
                    rows = section.findAll('tr')
                    cells = rows[0].findAll('td')
                    search = (
                        (u'Холодное водоснабжение', u'COLD_WATER'),
                        (u'Горячее водоснабжение', u'HOT_WATER'))
                    for q in search:
                        if cells[0].text == q[0]:
                            value = cells[1].text
                            if value == u'Установлен':
                                spans = section.findAll('tr', recursive=False)[-1].findAll('span')
                                value = ', '.join([value] + list(filter(
                                    lambda a: a != u'Не заполнено',
                                    map(
                                        lambda a: getattr(a, 'text'),
                                        (spans[1], cells[2], cells[3], spans[-1])))))
                            result[q[-1]] = value.strip().encode('utf-8')

                #write to output
                csvwriter_housedata.writerow(dict(result,
                                                  LAT=lat,
                                                  LON=lon,
                                                  HOUSE_ID=house_id,
                                                  ADDRESS=address.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  FIAS=fias,
                                                  YEAR=year.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  LASTUPDATE=lastupdate.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  SERVICEDATE_START=servicedate_start.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  SERIE=serie.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  HOUSE_TYPE=house_type.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  CAPFOND=capfond.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  MGMT_COMPANY=mgmt_company.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  MGMT_COMPANY_LINK=mgmt_company_link.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  AVAR=avar.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  LEVELS_MAX=levels_max.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  LEVELS_MIN=levels_min.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  DOORS=doors.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  ROOM_COUNT=room_count.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  ROOM_COUNT_LIVE=room_count_live.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  ROOM_COUNT_NONLIVE=room_count_nonlive.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  AREA=area.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  AREA_LIVE=area_live.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  AREA_NONLIVE=area_nonlive.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  AREA_GEN=area_gen.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  AREA_LAND=area_land.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  AREA_PARK=area_park.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  #CADNO=cadno.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  ENERGY_CLASS=energy_class.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  BLAG_PLAYGROUND=blag_playground.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  BLAG_SPORT=blag_sport.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  BLAG_OTHER=blag_other.encode('utf-8'),
                                                  OTHER=other.encode('utf-8')))
                return True

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        session = requesocks.session()
        session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150',
                           'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150'}
        try:
            session.get('http://google.com').text
        except:
            print('Tor isn\'t running or not configured properly. Read README.md')
            sys.exit(1)

        tid = args.id #2280999
        lvl1_link = 'http://www.reformagkh.ru/myhouse?tid=' + tid #+ '&sort=alphabet&item=mkd'
        house_link = 'http://www.reformagkh.ru/myhouse/profile/'
        #house_id = 8625429


        region = namedtuple('reg', 'lvl1name lvl2name lvl3name lvl1tid lvl2tid lvl3tid')

        #init errors.log
        f_errors = open('errors.txt','wb')
        f_ids = open('ids.txt','wb')

        #init csv for housedata
        f_housedata_name = args.output_name   #data/housedata.csv
        f_housedata = open(f_housedata_name,'wb')
        fieldnames_data = ('LAT','LON','HOUSE_ID','ADDRESS','FIAS','YEAR','LASTUPDATE','SERVICEDATE_START','SERIE','HOUSE_TYPE','CAPFOND','MGMT_COMPANY','MGMT_COMPANY_LINK','AVAR','LEVELS_MAX','LEVELS_MIN','DOORS','ROOM_COUNT','ROOM_COUNT_LIVE','ROOM_COUNT_NONLIVE','AREA','AREA_LIVE','AREA_NONLIVE','AREA_GEN','AREA_LAND','AREA_PARK','CADNO','ENERGY_CLASS','BLAG_PLAYGROUND','BLAG_SPORT','BLAG_OTHER','OTHER','COLD_WATER','HOT_WATER')
        fields_str = ','.join(fieldnames_data)
        f_housedata.write(fields_str+'\n')
        f_housedata.close()

        f_housedata = open(f_housedata_name,'ab')

        csvwriter_housedata = csv.DictWriter(f_housedata, fieldnames=fieldnames_data)

        regs = get_data_links(args.id)

        for reg in regs:
            if reg[5] != '' or len([i for i in regs if reg[4] in i]) == 1: #can't use Counter with cnt(elem[4] for elem in regs)[reg[4]] because of the progressbar
                    print(reg[0].decode('utf8') + ', ' + reg[1].decode('utf8') + ', ' + reg[2].decode('utf8'))
                    #get list of houses
                    if reg[5] == '': 
                        houses_ids = get_house_list('http://www.reformagkh.ru/myhouse/list?tid=' + reg[4])
                    else:
                        houses_ids = get_house_list('http://www.reformagkh.ru/myhouse/list?tid=' + reg[5])

                    pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=[Bar('=', '[', ']'), ' ', Counter(), ' of ' + str(len(houses_ids)), ' ', ETA()]).start()
                    pbar.maxval = len(houses_ids)

                    i = 0
                    for house_id in houses_ids:
                        i = i+1
                        res = get_housedata(house_link,str(house_id),reg[0],reg[3],reg[1],reg[4])
                        if res == False:
                            change_proxy()
                            res = get_housedata(house_link,str(house_id),reg[0],reg[3],reg[1],reg[4])
                        pbar.update(pbar.currval+1)
                    pbar.finish()

        f_housedata.close()
        f_errors.close()
        f_ids.close()  








 Traceback (most recent call last):                      ] 0 of 0 ETA:  --:--:--
      File "get_reformagkh_data-v3.py", line 404, in <module>
        pbar.finish()
      File "C:\Users\Dima\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\progressbar\__init__.py", line 320, in finish
        self.update(self.maxval)
      File "C:\Users\Dima\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\progressbar\__init__.py", line 283, in update
        self.fd.write(self._format_line() + '\r')
      File "C:\Users\Dima\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\progressbar\__init__.py", line 243, in _format_line
        widgets = ''.join(self._format_widgets())
      File "C:\Users\Dima\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\progressbar\__init__.py", line 233, in _format_widgets
        widget = result[index].update(self, portion)
      File "C:\Users\Dima\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\progressbar\widgets.py", line 261, in update
        marker *= int(pbar.currval / pbar.maxval * width)
    ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Выдает ошибку деления на ноль, хотя вчера еще все работало. Сразу говорю, не шарю, просто на работе надо сделать парсинг и никто ничего не знает.

Comment: Забыли прилижитъ код?

Comment: извиняюсь, приложил

Comment: Вопрос решили. Дело в количестве городов в коде, открываемых на сайте. В коде прописано 10000, а сайт поддерживает показывать только 100 за раз. Таким образом - количество домов он не получал, сл-но считал его за 0, и отсюда возникла ошибка деления на ноль.Надеюсь, кому-то поможет!